# Custom Alert component is not showing at ngOnit

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to implement the following Alert component implementation from this post:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/06/25/angular-2-4-alert-toaster-notifications

UPDATE: [Angular material create alert similar to bootstrap alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526390/angular-material-create-alert-similar-to-bootstrap-alerts) I use this, it's similar but don't uses an Array.

Above code, makes it possible to just trigger the AlertService and then let it generate an error. I encounter the problem that it's not showing the alert at the start and ngOnInit of my component that triggers the alertService.

When I put click event to show the alert it shows the alert, but not if I just call it in my ngOnit:

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
    private alertService: AlertService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.role = this.authenticationService.getRole();
    this.alertService.info('test alert message!');
    this.getDataFromRoute();
  }
}
```

In my template I just have `<alert></alert>` or whatever the selector is.

If I need to provide more code than already provided by the link let me know. I don't think it's needed as the code is simply copy pasted directly.

TL;DR: Alert shows on button click event, but not if you just want it to appear at page load.

Comment: please create an stackbliz

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is likely to be the view not being ready, Angular offers a lifecycle hook that fires when the view is ready, try this. Here is the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit). If you can get this working in a button click this is likely to work well.

**Solution**

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';

class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

constructor (private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.alertService.info('test alert message!');
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

**Why**

The `ngOninit` is the ideal place to work with any logic in regards to setting up the component / opening subscriptions, but try and avoid running any logic in here that has to interact with your template (HTML). You will find any logic that works with the template should be done within the `AfterViewInit` Lifecycle hook as mentioned this is only fired after the template is ready to be interacted with.

In the case this causes `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` you can wrap the call in a

```
setTimeout( () => { //logic here });
```

or manually force [detectChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges)

Inject `ChangeDetectRef` in your constructor like above .and then within the `ngAfterViewInit` call the `detectChanges()` like shown above.

Comment: why someone down vote this? answer not 100% true but I don't think someone should down vote it

Comment: Im not too sure, I had the import in the wrong place to start with, might have been that. What would top this up to 100%?

Comment: this expression change error is indeed something I tried to fix, I will try to put the setTimeout (which seems hacky to me btw).

Comment: Yeah setTimeout I would view as hacky, shouldnt be hard to find some resources on detectChanges() though, which will also rid you of the error. Did the toast appear?

Comment: Yes, it did. Do you figure detectChanges() is better than using setTimeout? 

Also, I don't know why all the answers get downvoted.

Comment: Yeah detectChanges() over setTimeout, proper way to handle it :-)

Comment: Silly question, how do I use that exactly?

Comment: Perfect, I googled it and found the changedetectorRef, this works! marked it as an answer, thank you for your help!